# Object destructure vs assign (performance)

Tags: javascript, performance, object, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I was thinking about performance of object destructure vs assign. I made a simple test:

```
const ITERATIONS = 999999;

const simpleObj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const newSimpleObj = { d: 4 };


const s1 = new Date().getTime();
for (let i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {
    const n = Object.assign({}, simpleObj, newSimpleObj);
}
console.log('End1:', new Date().getTime() - s1);


const s2 = new Date().getTime();
for (let i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {
    const n = { ...simpleObj, ...newSimpleObj };
}
console.log('End2:', new Date().getTime() - s2);
```

Do I make it right? In this test End1 shows 172ms and End2 shows 138ms. It's really simple and I think that in more complex functions it could make more difference. I couldn't find any article with benchmarks or statements that could prove that there are benefits from using destructuring over assign method. Is there any other benefits or disadvantages of this solution like memory efficiency, code quality or similar?

UPDATE:
I tried http://jsben.ch/ and it showed that `assign` is faster, but https://jsbench.me/ presented almost 45% advantage of object destructuring.

Comment: I assume you mean **destructure** (de-structure) instead of actually destroying the objects? If you really mean deleting objects from memory (destruction) then object deletion from memory in js happens via garbage collection and you can't really predict when the interpreter will do garbage collection.

Comment: [What is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Yeah, of course I was thinking about destructure however my dictionary did the job for me. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can see a test that was maid on FireFox: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/57602

In this test the `assign` won.[image]

Comment: Quite interesting  However it probably doesn't close the topic?

Comment: I tried http://jsben.ch/ and it showed that `assign` is faster, but https://jsbench.me/ presented almost 45% advantage of object destructuring.